# AJAX запрос на удаленный домен

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Всем доброго дня.

Как и многие здесь, сижу сейчас пишу систему на php.

Мне понадобилось получить данные с другого домена. У них в веб интерфейсе я подсмотрел ajax запрос:

```
      $.ajax({
          url: '/lenta/get_last_opened_organization',
          success: function( data ){
            $("#last_viewed").html(data)
          }
      });
```

Взял его и вставил себе с ссылкой на их домен, получилось так:

```
          $.ajax({
              url: 'http://domen/lenta/get_last_opened_organization',
              success: function( data ){
                $("#last_viewed").html(data)
              }
          });
```

При выполнении запроса браузер сообщил мне:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domen/lenta/get_last_opened_organization. Origin http://my-domen.ru is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Я точно не понимаю почему но в доступе отказано.
Вопрос в том как притвориться что делаешь запрос с их домена..

p.s.
В документации jQquery AJAX нашел следующее:

```
Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
```

Означает ли это проблема нерешаема?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доступ на другие домены запрещен в целях безопасности. Чтобы получить ответ с другого домена, этот самый домен должен быть настроен для этого заранее. Почитайте это [Обмен данными между доменами](http://javascript.ru/ajax/cross-origin-2) и это [JSONP](http://javascript.ru/blog/Ilya-Kantor/Zagruzka-dannyh-cherez-SCRIPT-s-otlovom-oshibok)

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте на своем сервере php-скрипт, пусть ajax обращается к вашему скрипту, а скрипт по средством curl обратиться к тому сайта, получив результат, передаст уже вашему сайту.

Comment: Вариант, Бабай, хорошая идея

Answer (score 1):

Это называется политика безопасности, нечего шастать по чужим сайтам.

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то нужно изменить текущий домен на нужный, **document.domain=''**, вроде так, редактора под рукой нету.

Comment: При попытке изменить document.domain в js вылетает SECURITY_ERR (

Comment: тогда без вариантов(